# error : No operations allowed after statement closed

Tags: java, sql, connection, prepared-statement

I'm trying to excute this code but I have this error , I know I have to close the connection with

```
preparedStatement.close()
```

but it's closed before the treatement is finished and it gives me the following error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
```

my code

```
    private void fakesAssociate(List<Map<String, Object>> Employees) {
    coreEmployees.forEach(row -> {
        try {
            myrefJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO `n_associate` (`active`, `first_name`, `birthday`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? );", preparedStatement -> {
                   preparedStatement.setBoolean(1, true);
                   preparedStatement.setString(2, String.valueOf(row.get("usual_first_name")));

                Date birthdate = ((Date) row.get("birth_date"));
                if (birthdate != null) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTime(birthdate);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1970);
                    preparedStatement.setDate(3, new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
                } else {
                    preparedStatement.setDate(3, null);
                }

                preparedStatement.close();
            });

            });
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            String queryAssociate = "UPDATE n_associate SET  `active`= ?  " +
                WHERE n_associate.first_name = ?;";

            myrefJdbcTemplate.update(queryAssociate, preparedStatement -> {

                    preparedStatement.setBoolean(1, false);
                preparedStatement.close();

            });
        }
    });
}
```

please help to find out how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Don't close the statement. JdbcTemplate will need it open so it can execute it. JdbcTemplate will take care of closing the statement when it's finished using it.

Comment: yes i added it because I have this error of leak of memory 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' when I made some researches I find out that I have to close connection in order to free some memory

Comment: You've been misinformed; OOME and closing resources have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @marie you need to investigate why the heap memory is running out, most likely this isn't it.